# "Merge all outputs to a single assembly" is creating two assemblies?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a single web application (consisting, of course, of several `.cs` and `.aspx`/`aspx.designer.cs` files). When I precompile it for publishing, two assemblies are created.

Decompiling it, it appears one assembly contains the non-page source files (`.cs`), and the other assembly contains the rest (`.aspx`/`aspx.designer.cs`).

Since all the files were in the same project (with only .NET Framework references), I was expecting a single assembly. Why is there two?

Answer (score 0):

It could be due to Precompile settings configured already with your project.

Right click the project name in Solution Explorer, and then choose Publish >
Select the Settings tab > Expand File Publish Options, and then select Precompile during publishing > Configure.

[image]

There you can see the settings and update them for your needs.